# implement a user-based Authorization filter in .net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing a simple WebApi .Net Core CRUD on CleanArchitecture, going to implement the following security aspect.
(1) Authentication -Token-Based Jwt
(2) Authorization:
How can I implement a user-based Authorization scenario like "An authorized User can only change their contact" using Authorization Filter?
I can do it at the action level as follow, but want to use filters!

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPut("{userName}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateContact(string userName, UpdateContactCommand command)
{
  if (User.Identity.Name == userName)
      return Ok(await _mediator.Send(command));
}
```

Comment: Why not do it in your action,or in a service?